# Indexing: big Events vs. storage lookup. Downsides of having big Events

Tags: events, indexing, subsquid

**Problem statement:**
While indexing it's impossible to extract information from the Extrinsic call when Extrinsic has optional parameters (default if none).

Solutions:

- storage lookup (seems suboptimal due to the direct chain access). Subsquid is used for indexing, and it doesn't support off-chain storage lookups;
- extending the Event (it becomes big).

I assume it is not a common practice to have an Event with 10-15+ fields. The only downside I see - it takes up some space in the block.
Another upside of Event extension - it simplifies indexing code since an Extrinsic handler or storage lookup is no longer needed.

**Questions:**
Are there any other downsides to having "thick" Events?
Trade-offs: big events vs. storage lookup?

Some related links:

- [appending an event is a constant time operation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4452/1803);
- [events are flushed from the state every block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219830/what-is-the-cost-of-event-storage-in-substrate?_gl=1*sftly5*_ga*OTM1NzA4MDU0LjE2NDcwMDkwNTQ.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2MzYxNzYyOS4zLjEuMTY2MzYxODEwNi4wLjAuMA..).

Comment: Why are storage lookups suboptimal? As long as they are done offchain there are no problems with storage lookups.

Comment: We use Subsquid, which only works with the chain while querying the storage.

Comment: I don't get your answer.

Comment: An off-chain storage lookups are not supported by Subsquid, which is our Indexer. For every storage lookup, it goes to the chain directly. That's why I think it's suboptimal.
Extending event also seems to be a bad choice.
I assume this discussion is more about Subsquid and its features and less about Substrate. I just wanted to elaborate on the downsides of having big Events.

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Index the arguments of extrinsics? You can query the nodes' storage all you want from subsquid, that is not sub-optimal. Unless maybe you are a validator and have performance concerns.

Comment: Suboptimal is querying chain each block while indexing billions of blocks. I'm trying to understand the downsides of having big Events with 10-20 fields.

Comment: Perhaps someone can turn this into an answer: the main downside of Events with 10-20 fields is that each event incurs some storage overhead and computational overhead during cleanup. In practice, as Events are themselves stored (temporarily) in the state of the chain, there is little meaningful difference between emitting larger events versus emitting more smaller events.

Comment: But it sounds like there might be an XY problem here; the statement 'While indexing it's impossible to extract information from the Extrinsic call when Extrinsic has optional parameters' is suspicious. The parity-scale-codec (see [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/scale-codec/)) encodes Optional values as 0x00 when `None`.